# @QuarkusTest with JWT is unstable

Tags: jwt, quarkus, quarkus-testing

We have lots of integration-tests that send HTTP requests to our services.
The services use JWT-RBAC.
In the integration-tests, we create a JWT on the fly and attach it to the HTTP "Authorization"-header as bearer-token.
Usually everything works as expected.

Unfortunately, *some* of the integration-tests fail, when we run them within a GitHub-Action.
Not always and not always the same tests, but mostly.
The symptom typically is, that we get a 401 back without our endpoint-code being called.
There are no exceptions or other unusual messages in the log, even at debug level.

From the http-client's log I can see, that the authorization-header is sent, although I can't see the actual content because in the log it is replaced by "***".

When using @TestSecurity and @JwtSecurity, everything works as expected (at least wherever I tried it).
But when using this approach, we would test something else, than what our services will receive in prod.

Are @QuarkusTests expected to work the way we want to use them?
What other approach should we try?

We are using Quarkus 2.13 with Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this indeterministic behavior was caused by a defect in the old Quarkus version (2.13.1) we were using.
With Quarkus version 2.16.5 the tests do no longer fail.